# Give two examples of dense open sets and demonstrate that their intersection is dense in ℝ.

Tags: real-analysis

> Give two examples of dense open sets and demonstrate that their intersection is dense in ℝ.

I'm aware that the intersection of 2 dense open sets will be dense in ℝ. However, I don't know how to create two specific examples of dense open sets. I think that there's a way to show what the problem is asking with the union of open sets that are dense.

I have checked the similar questions, and to my understanding none of them are answering exactly what I'm asking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The wording of the problem does not clearly indicate how many "dense open sets" we are expected to intersect.  Just 2? Or any finite number? A countable number?  It obviously fails if you are allowed to intersect an uncountably infinite number of "dense open sets".

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x \}$ is always open and dense for $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry. Yes, just 2 specific examples.

Comment: @TheoBendit My largest hang up often is notation. What exactly does the ' ∖ ' denote?

Comment: @GL007 The $\setminus$ is the set difference operation. The set $A \setminus B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ that are not in $B$ (it's also sometimes denoted $A - B$). So $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ is the set of all real numbers except $x$.

Comment: There are not non-trivial set open and dense. A trivial example is $\mathbb R\setminus \{x_1,,x_2,\cdots,x_n\}$